# SQL Server Profiler but in Postgres DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I worked a lot with SQL Management studio and there i often used the SQL Server Profiler to see exactly what queries was send to the Database when i clicked on different things in the GUI.

Now im working with a postgres database and with Dbeaver. Does anyone know if there is some similar function i can use there?

PS. im not searching for a performance analyse. I just want to see the queries that runs in realtime on the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Use the session manager. From the menu select **[Database] -> [Tools] -> [Session Manager]**.
[image]

To see the real query that is executed in a SQL tool click the hilighted area on the picture below.
[image]